# Betrayal at House on the Hill - Scenario 50 - Do the Clue Tokens drop when a character dies?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

During this haunt, the adventures collect clue tokens.  According to the haunts special rules, the clues can be

- Traded, like any other item
- Stolen, like any other item

Do they 'drop' in an item pile when the character dies, like other items?  The rules seem silent on this issue.

Comment: Its been soo long since I've played this game...  It might help if you dug up links to (or posted excerpts of) the relevant rules.

Comment: I tried to research this by looking at the online rules, but I don't see the scenario you're referring to. Are you maybe playing with the first edition? http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=ah/faqs/hoth

Comment: Looking at the release dates, I think maybe the online rules you're linking are the first edition, and I'm using the second edition.  The document you linked is 2005;  the release date for the new edition (which I just purchased) is 2010.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't even notice that. I guess they haven't updated for the new release yet. Didn't even occur to me since they link to that from the page about the new release. Go figure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Page 12 of the rule book says:

> Many haunts put one or more item tokens in the house, which have special rules for their use. Unless the haunt says otherwise, item tokens can be traded, dropped, or stolen just like item and omen cards.

I'm not sure why they felt it necessary to mention that they can be stolen or traded in the haunt, since that would already be the case according the above rule. However, it does *not* say they cannot be dropped, therefore they can. If they can be dropped, then I would assume they are also dropped when a character dies.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the page reference, especially :)