# Multiple questions about Betrayal at the House on the Hill

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

We bought and played our first game of *Betrayal at the House on the Hill* and we had a great time. Our haunt scenario was with a mummy, I won't spoil more about it.

- Whose turn is it when the haunt starts? Is it the turn of the betrayer (who just activated the haunt and who's the betrayer) or is it just normal and is it the player next to him?
- In some haunts the betrayer can control multiple characters and/or monsters (like the mummy). Can the betrayer use both his explorer and all of his other minions in the same turn or is it one character per turn?
- An explorer had found a clue in the library and took the "knowledge roll" token as proof. But then he got killed. We made a quick house rule where the dying explorer had the chance to yell out the clue to the survivors in the house doing a 3 dice 5+ roll. It wasn't clear if the clue token could be dropped and picked up, or even shared with other explorers. In a real life situation I would definitely share this information.

Comment: Your third question is already answered at http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/671/betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill-scenario-50-do-the-clue-tokens-drop-when-a-cha?rq=1

Comment: @bwarner I don't believe that that's the same question. The answer given there talks about "item tokens", not "knowledge roll tokens".

Comment: Your questions have already been answered, but next time, please limit yourself to one question per question. Also, you can accept the answer if you consider it correct by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: People like you make it annoying to post on Overflow.

Answer (score 9):

1. When the haunt begins, the player to the left of the traitor always takes the first turn. It doesn't matter who had the last turn (the person to reveal the haunt will not always be the traitor). There are a couple scenarios that change this, but they will specify their own rules in the haunt description. Rulebook, page 11:

   > **Haunt Turn Order**
   >   The first turn always starts with the player to the traitor’s
   >   left and goes clockwise (further away from the traitor).
2. The monsters get their own "monster turn" after the traitor's turn. So the traitor does not control both himself and the monsters in the same turn, but he does control all the monsters right after he's done with his regular turn. Rulebook, page 11:

   > After each hero has had a turn, the traitor gets his or hertraitor turn. After the traitor’s turn, any monsters controlled by the traitor get a monster turn. (One player gets two turns: one for the traitor and one for the monsters.
3. All information always openly shared between the heroes. So it doesn't matter which hero found the clue and has the knowledge roll token; all that matters is the total number of knowledge roll tokens found by all heroes combined. From the [FAQ](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=ah/faqs/hoth):

   > If someone in the house makes a knowledge roll to find out a particular piece of information (a mummy's name, a room that needs to be visited, etc.), do all the other explorers know this information automatically?
   >
   > > **Yes. Perhaps they all have walkie-talkies.**

Answer (score 0):

1. It is the player after (to the left of) the Betrayer's turn.  When the Haunt starts, every player gets a turn before the Betrayer takes his turn.
2. It probably depends on the actual Haunt, but typically the Betrayer can activate every character he controls, whether they be his own explorer, an explorer he has taken over, a monster, or a board effect.